# Laravel 4 not getting JSON from input Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, laravel

I have read and worked with the other posts about this and it appears the version of Laravel 4 I just downloaded has more changes made to the way the JSON input is handled by a controller.

`$input = Input::json()->all();` gives me errors as if I am referring to something that does not exist when I request some part of the payload after doing a PUT request. And without `->all();` I get a symfony error.
Does anyone know how to get good JSON from backbone in Laravel 4's latest version?

Currently, I am doing the long way around to get my data, ie:

```
    $input_title = Input::get('title');
        $input_completed = Input::get('completed');

        $task = Task::find($id);
        $task->title = $input_title;
        $task->completed = $input_completed;
        $task->save();
```

Yes, I am doing the tutorial on tutsplus to learn laravel/backbone, so a little noob patience is apreciated.

The error I get when using `Input::get();` is:
{"error":{"type":"UnexpectedValueException","message":"The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"array\" given.","file":"/Users/brentlawson23/Sites/laravel4App/bootstrap/compiled.php","line":16858}}

I really want to get the Laravel-specific answer instead of using straight php to stringify the payload.

I get same error using just `Input::json();`

For the current beta of Laravel 4, Input::json(); is not getting a stringified version of the request payload that can be used to create a new row in a table, nor does Input::json()->all(); (hoping to play nice with the ParameterBag from symfony). I have tried json_encode among other hacks and basically every step of the way in this tut, I hit some brick wall. Anyone have a suggestion based on what I have presented here?

Today I got this when simply trying to echo the result of `$input = Input::json();` :
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string in /Users/brentlawson23/Sites/laravel4App/app/controllers/TasksController.php line 45","file":"/Users/brentlawson23/Sites/laravel4App/app/controllers/TasksController.php","line":45}}

Yes, I have studied the Symfony API.

Comment: Can you just use `Input::get()` (no parameter) ?

Comment: so not working actually, simple and intuitive and I appreciate it, but it is giving same error

Comment: Could you include the error in your question, it may help someone to reproduce/debug.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Symfony ParameterBag API](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html)

Comment: Yeah and the options seem not to include a method (other than all()) for dealing with more than one key->value pair - I am getting a string with json_encode($input) tha looks like it should work but to no avail so far

Comment: If you get json input from Backbone you don't have decode it. What do you get just with `var_dump(Input::all());` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Input from **Backbone** is converted to array in **Laravel**. On tutsplus, Jeffrey Way is using object. So I was trying to do this (like in tutorial):

```
return $input->title // using object,but got an error.
```

If I change that line to:

```
return $input["title"] // everything works fine with array.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also working through the Backbone tutorial on tuts+. If I'm right in assuming are you stuck on the Creating New Contacts section? Below is how I got it to work for me, in ContactController.php:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    Contact::create(array(
        'first_name' => $input['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $input['last_name'],
        'email_address' => $input['email_address'],
        'description' => $input['description']
    ));
}
```

And then also needed to update app/models/Contact.php with the below:

```
class Contact extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address', 'description');
```

}

That should get it working for you and insert the contact into the database. If I've misread let me know and I can have another look.

Cheers,

Sean

Comment: for me Input::all() is empty!!
but Input::getContent() has a string of JSON data.

Comment: @Sean yes! your solution worked very well. I'm also working on tuts+ contacts app. Don't forget to add 'public $timestamps = false' in the 'Contact' model if you are working on this same app. thanks